# SSRS: Adding a line to a stacked bar column chart summing values based on series

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, linechart, stacked-chart

I have a requirement to add a line to a stacked bar column chart which calculates the sum of only 2 values based on a specific Series.  For example, I have a stacked column chart which is counting the total number (Values) of people that fall under a particular status (Series Group).  I want to add a line that represents the Sum of the values of only 2 of the available Series (ie New + Enrolled).
The screenshot shows my current settings.  I know that is I want to add a line chart, I would need to add another StatusCount to the Values section, however I only want to show one line representing the total of New and Enrolled.

Is this something that is even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit your dataset to pass in the required values then it's fairly simple. Lets say we now have 5 Status values; Enrolled, Suppressed, New, Opportunity and NewEnrol.

NewEnrol will contain the sum of the New and Enrolled values.

A sample of your dataset output might look something like this.

```
Month      Status      StatusCount
'Apr 2017' Enrolled    160
'Apr 2017' Suppressed  40
'Apr 2017' New         15
'Apr 2017' Opportunity 270
'Apr 2017' NewEnrol    175
```

In your chart, add a new value in the Values panel (top right panel  in your image). Set the value to an expression, something like.

```
=IIF(Fields!Status.Value = "NewEnrol", SUM(Fields!StatusCount.Value), nothing)
```

We will also have to exclude the series from the original stacked columns so we can do somehting similar again. Change the current Value from `[Sum(SatusCount)]` to an expression something like

```
=IIF(Fields!Status.Value <> "NewEnrol", SUM(Fields!StatusCount.Value), nothing)
```

That should be it.
You might also want to hide the legend for this series, you can do that from the Series properties.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved, though you need to be a bit clever with your data and how it is passed to and therefore displayed on your chart.  You can see how this is done here: [Combining stacked column chart and line chart in report builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743859/combining-stacked-column-chart-and-line-chart-in-report-builder/41744755#41744755)